# How to improve performance when updating directly into innerHTML with Angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an inputfield to accept `searchTerm` inputs. A Directive is attached to each `<tr>`. It is responsible for search and highlight any matching text in this table below.

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let car of cars, index as i" [highlight]="searchTerm">
       <td>{{ car?.name}}</td>
       <td>{{ car?.color}}</td>
       <td>{{ car?.origin}}</td>
       <td>{{ car?.owner}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The directive contains script that cycle through `<tr>` and deep into `<td>` searching (using regexp) for matching text and append the highlight span class.

```
const highlightSpanTag1 = '<span class="highlight">';
const highlightSpanTag2 = '</span>';
// regexp search ....
// appending highlightSpanTag1/highlightSpanTag2 between matching text
newInnerHtml += .....
```

Directive script below:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[highlight]'
})

public search(): void {
   const attachedNode = this.hostEl.nativeElement; // =====> this is <tr> //
   attachedNode.children.forEach((childNode) => {
      this.highlight(childNode); // =====> this is <td> //
   });
}

private highlight(childNode): void {
   ...
   ...
   childNode.innerHTML = newInnerHtml; // =====> this is going to execute when searchTerm change, causing some bad performance issues
}
```

When I have hundreds of table rows, I can see in the debug console that the performance is dropping and CPU usage is over 99%. I discovered that this line `childNode.innerHTML` is the problem. How can this be avoided?

My first thought was to test on `requestAnimationFrame(this.highlight.bind(this))` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Why not take a look inside a component that already does this and see what they do? A suggestion would be take a look at the source code for the ngx-bootstrap type ahead component as it does search highlighting.

Comment: Taking a quick look they use <span [innerHtml]="highlight(match, query)"> and have a hightligh function in the TypeScript at https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/typeahead/typeahead-container.component.ts

Comment: In any case, Nothing can reduce the number of comparisons and re-rendering per button click. O(n_rows x n_columns x len_searchTerm x l_avg_td). Make your table lazyload or add Angular 7 Virtual Scroll or at least virtual/lazy highlight. Also run the function highlight(match, query); once a delay of key press is more than x seconds i.e. the user input is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the source code for the ngx-bootstrap component at

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/typeahead/typeahead-container.component.html

They use

```
<span [innerHtml]="highlight(match, query)">
```

and have a highlight function in the TypeScript.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/typeahead/typeahead-container.component.ts

This is going to be much more performant to generate the html as you go rather than render a DOM and the modify the DOM.

So try

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let car of cars, index as i">
       <td [innerHtml]="hightlight(car?.name, searchTerm)"></td>
       <td [innerHtml]="hightlight(car?.color, searchTerm)"></td>
       <td [innerHtml]="hightlight(car?.origin, searchTerm)"></td>
       <td [innerHtml]="hightlight(car?.owner, searchTerm)"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then put your highlighting code in your TypeScript.

Comment: Using `[innerHTML]` is instead 20times faster than a directive in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, Nothing can reduce the number of comparisons and re-rendering per button click.

```
O(n_rows x n_columns x len_searchTerm x l_avg_td)
```

If you have hundreds of table rows, that's really a load on the frontend.

Make your table **lazyload** or add **Angular 7 Virtual Scroll** or at least **virtual/lazy highlight**.

Also, **throttle-run** the function **highlight(match, query);** once a delay of key press is more than *x seconds* i.e. the user input is complete.

Try Optimizing your table with **Angular 7 Virtual Scroll**.

https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c

Here, you would do comparisons only on visible elements to highlight the data you need. Its a performance booster.